# initialize non-static hashmap with standard keys in java

Tags: java, hashmap, initialization, non-static

Am looking for an efficient way to initialize a HashMap given that it's keys remain the same for any object created of the class it belongs to.

My current implementation initializes the HashMap everytime a new class object is created.

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you have a class Foo with a field Bar that is a HashMap of some type and for all Foo, the HashMap Bar contains the same keys?  Do the values change?

Comment: Yes, the values change, and you've understood right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a template Map, and use .clone() to generate new instances. You could also create a custom Map implementation that uses a copy-on-write policy to refer to a template "parent" Map.

Comment: something along the lines of *shallowCopy = (Map<String, Object>) ((HashMap<String, Object>) data).clone();*, where data is a template static map?

Comment: Yep... That's one way which might work for you. TMTOWTDI.  (There's More Than One Way To Do It).

Comment: it'd sure be nice to see another way...:)

Comment: Create your own HashMap extension facade that takes a "parent" Map as a constructor.  In all the access methods, check to see if the key is known to the instance first.  If there, return that; if not, return the parent's instance value.